# face_recognition package usage is unclear

Tags: ros, face-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What steps exactly do I have to run in what order for [face_recognition](http://wiki.ros.org/face_recognition) package?

I assumed the following, which doesn't seem to be working for me.

1. Publish `/camera/image_raw` I'm using shows clearly my face
2. `rosrun face_recognition Fserver`
3. `rosrun face_recognition Fclient`
4. `rostopic pub -1 /fr_order face_recognition/FRClientGoal -- 2 "your_name"` or other rostopic command that are mentioned in [README.md](https://github.com/procrob/face_recognition/blob/catkin/README.md).

Also, if successful, what result can I expect? In general, well-accepted ROS package description has "published topics" or similar section (e.g. http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera#Published_Topics).

(This question is redirected from [a ticket](https://github.com/procrob/face_recognition/issues/5))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217444/face_recognition-package-usage-is-unclear/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2015-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The steps are correct. The above steps can be used to add your face to the database. Then, you can continue the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/face_recognition) to recognize faces. The package is based on [actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) , so you need to learn about actionlib to understand and use the face recognition package.

---

Originally posted by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) with karma: 143 on 2015-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michael_kong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29170/michael_kong/) on 2017-03-09**:
I have the same question, I did input the commands correctly, but I can't find any picture new in the date package.